# How to draw a circle on tip of a line with Canvas in android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, canvas, customization

[image]

Hello everyone. I need help about drawing a circle on tip of line with using canvas in android. If you know how to draw it, please help me! I analyze the source code of this custom progress bar library. I can do everything except that white cirle on line. Please help me! I am a junior android developer and I don't have enough experience about Canvas or other drawing libraries!

Comment: the link of library I used is this https://github.com/lopspower/CircularProgressBar/tree/master/circularprogressbar

Comment: Which line and what is tip of the line in the context here?

Comment: Animesh Sahu, the line is red one. The wanted tip of line is point where white circle placed. I want to add that white circle

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28180468/drawing-moving-circle-on-edge-of-circle this may help you

Answer (score 0):

The perfect solution is https://github.com/vhnguyen1001/android-circle-seekbar with some customazations on copy of source code for android